# webkit vs firefox height of text

Tags: firefox, webkit, vertical-alignment, css

I have quite large text (font size 28) I'm trying to align vertically in a fixed-height container.

I'm doing this by eye and just setting a margin-top so that it gets to the right spot.  However, when in Firefox, I need a margin-top of 20px, in Safari I need like 15px (else it's too far down).  I saw that the discrepancy was because in Safari the text element is taller than in Firefox and includes a slight amount of whitespace on top that doesn't show up in Firefox (in Firefox, the top of the text element is exactly when the text starts).

I've tried all kinda of display combinations with line-heights and perhaps adding a width/height for the text and whatnot.  Nothing works.

What can I do to make this consistent? I'd hate to use JS but it seems like the only option...

---

Comment: let's see the relevant html/css please! jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

For cross-browser CSS normalization I'd recommend a reset - YUI3 has a good one, Twitter Bootstrap is another good one. It basically sets paddings and margins to 0 so all browsers will behave and only adhere to YOUR css rules and not their own default rules.

For vertically aligning text to containers, if it's a single line of text, use the `line-height` property, and set it to equal the height of the container.

For example:

**CSS:**

```
div {
    height:300px;
    width: 400px;
    line-height: 300px;
    font-size:28px;
    background-color:#F0F0F0;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div>
   Some vertically centered text
</div>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Djvv7/

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply a css reset. Good practice to use one on all projects. The most famous I know of is: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/